# Iterating over a dictionary in Python starting from the middle

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

As we know we can get an iterator over a python dictionary using the following code:

```
(value for value in dict if <condition>)
```

Let's say I want to find the first True value, and I know it is somewhere in the middle of the dictionary. (python dictionaries keep track of insertion order from 3.6 and above)

Can I somehow start iterating from the middle of the dictionary with the intent of finding the first True value, with O(1) time complexity to get to that middle point?

Or is my only option to somehow always keep track of the first True value in the dictionary?

Comment: Even if you track the first True value, you won't be able to iterate from it.

Comment: It is not clear if you want to iterate starting from the first True value or you want to iterate to find this value.

Comment: I want to iterate to find that value, but I know its always somewhere in the middle (lets say its an LRU dictionary and keys that are too old are set to false) so iterating from the start is a waste of time.

Comment: I edited the post to make that clearer

Comment: Couldn't you make a linked list instead of a dictionary ? And keep track of the middle node

Comment: No, because of other time constraints of my code that a linked list couldnt acomplish, like O(1) search.

Comment: Since `dict.items` and `dict.keys` are not subscriptable, I don't think that what you want is possible. In general there is no way to start an iterator somewhere in the middle.

Comment: It is hard to give any definitive answer without more context. What's the problem of keeping track of the first True element in a separate variable? Does it change from time to time? How does it change? Maybe splitting the dict into two dicts "before" the True element and "after" the True element might help.